# Why is semicolon used in for loop instead of coma?

Tags: c, function, loops

Typically, all function arguments in C are separated with comma `,` e.g. `printf("Data",&a);` .

But for a `for` loop arguments are separated with semicolon ( `for(i=0;i<5;++i)`) Why is it so?

Comment: 1. Statements are seperated by semicola. 2. The resulting ambiguity would yield problems. 3. Because the C standard says so.

Comment: `for` is not a function, it's a keyword of the language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) is an operator and allows one to do things like

```
for (i=0,j=5; i<5; ++i, ++j)
```

PS: `for` is a keyword an not a function as pointed out above

> ```
> **ISO/IEC 9899:1999 §6.8.5.3 The for statement**
>
> The statement
>
> for ( clause-1 ; expression-2 ; expression-3 ) statement
>
> behaves as follows: The expression expression-2 is the controlling expression that is evaluated before each execution of the loop body.
> ```
>
> The expression expression-3 is evaluated as a void expression after
>   each execution of the loop body. If clause-1 is a declaration, the
>   scope of any variables it declares is the remainder of the declaration
>   and the entire loop, including the other two expressions; it is
>   reached in the order of execution before the first evaluation of the
>   controlling expression. If clause-1 is an expression, it is evaluated
>   as a void expression before the first evaluation of the controlling
>   expression.133)
>
> ```
> Both clause-1 and expression-3 can be omitted. An omitted expression-2 is replaced by a nonzero constant.
>
> 133) Thus, clause-1 specifies initialization for the loop, possibly declaring one or more variables for use in the loop; the
> ```
>
> controlling expression, expression-2, specifies an evaluation made
>   before each iteration, such that execution of the loop continues until
>   the expression compares equal to 0; and expression-3 specifies an
>   operation (such as incrementing) that is performed after each
>   iteration.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that? It seems an unlikely reason.